# Hive to Vectorwise using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, ingres

I have Vectorwise 2.0.2 and Sqoop 1.4.1 installed.

When I'm trying to use `sqoop-export`:

```
sudo -u hdfs ./sqoop-export --driver com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver --connect jdbc:ingres://172.16.63.157:VW7/amit --username ingres -P -m 1 --table book_call_log --export-dir /user/hive/warehouse/book_call_log --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --verbose


Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Enter password: 
12/06/08 19:00:52 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
12/06/08 19:00:52 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
12/06/08 19:00:53 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM book_call_log AS t WHERE 1=0
```

The operation gets stuck here. No error is indicated and the prompt also does not appear.

Any help related to this is appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT t.* FROM book_call_log AS t WHERE 1=0` - WHERE 1=0 ?? o.O That SQL query will always give you an empty set...

Comment: Did you set the $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation as you are warned?

Comment: @Amit - Welcome to StackOverflow! From my experience using this site, well-formatted code attracts more eye-balls.. Just formatted it for you.